# Set breakpoint in the middle of a line Java with Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, recursion, breakpoints

I'm trying to see what's going on in a chain of recursive calls. Is there some way to set a breakpoint in the middle of a single line to see when the function is being called from each statement?

Example: fibonacci(term - 2) + (want to put a breakpoint here) fibonacci(term - 1)

Comment: Can't be done, you can only break on the line, and the evaluate the statements.  The return values from the functions will be evaluated first, then the math operations.  You could spearate the two calls over three lines if that makes it easier

Comment: This is a good reason not to write excessively terse code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible for some of the major IDE's like (Eclipse, Netbeans).
However, you can actually update your codes to such that you can evaluate them :

```
result1 = fibonacci(term - 2);
result2 = fibonacci(term - 1);
sum = result1 + result2;
```

The above code might not give you an elegant way of presenting your codes but can actually help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, but in some IDE's (Eclipse, IntelliJ) you can evaluate an expression that you highlight during debugging.

This could be useful if you wanted to see what `fibonaci(term-2)`, for example, produced.